# Adding class to input and label when creating select boxes in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

So Here is how the select boxes are being created:

```
    echo $this->Form->select('weekdays', array(
         '1'=>__('Manday'), 
         '2'=>__('Tuesday'), 
         '3'=>__('Wednesday'), 
         '4'=>__('Thursday'), 
         '5'=>__('Friday'), 
         '6'=>__('Satruday'), 
         '7'=>__('Sunday')), 
       array('multiple'=>'checkbox', 'class'=>'checkbox2'));
```

which outputs 7 checbox with the following HTML markup:

```
<div class="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" name="data[Event][weekdays][]" value="1" id="EventWeekdays1" />
<label for="EventWeekdays1">Monday</label>
</div>
```

But the expected output that is needed is this:

```
<div class="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" 
       name="data[Event][EventWeekdays1]" 
       id="EventWeekdays1" class="css-checkbox" value="1" />
<label for="EventWeekdays1" class="css-label">Mandag</label>
</div>
```

I have been through documentation but cannot seem to find an option to add clases to both input and label attributes when using `Form->select`

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just FormHelper-approved things:

```
$options = array(
     '1'=>__('Manday'), 
     '2'=>__('Tuesday'), 
     '3'=>__('Wednesday'), 
     '4'=>__('Thursday'), 
     '5'=>__('Friday'), 
     '6'=>__('Satruday'), 
     '7'=>__('Sunday'));

$this->Form->input('weekdays', array(
                       'type' => 'select',
                       'div' => array('class'=>'checkbox2'),
                       'multiple'=>'checkbox', 
                       'class'=>'css-checkbox',
                       'options' => $options,
                       'label' => array('class'=>'css-label')));
```

[Docs here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options)

Answer (score 0):

I think after reading your question you would be better off building the markup yourself and loop trough your $options on the checkboxes you need, so:

```
$options = array(
     '1'=>__('Manday'), 
     '2'=>__('Tuesday'), 
     '3'=>__('Wednesday'), 
     '4'=>__('Thursday'), 
     '5'=>__('Friday'), 
     '6'=>__('Satruday'), 
     '7'=>__('Sunday'));

<div class="checkbox2">
 <?php foreach($options as $k => $v): ?>

  <input type="checkbox" 
     name="data[Event][EventWeekdays<?php echo $k ?>]" 
     id="EventWeekdays<?php echo $k ?>" class="css-checkbox" value="<?php echo $v ?>" />
  <label for="EventWeekdays<?php echo $k ?>" class="css-label">Mandag</label>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Not the better way to do it, but it works and can be a solution to your problem. Hope it helps!